# TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable under nginx+uwsgi+django+centos7 Never seen before

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos, uwsgi

I have an annoying problem thest days.There are errors from uwsgi.log in the project I am creating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Envs/magicmall2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
  File "/root/Envs/magicmall2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Envs/magicmall2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 409, in url_patterns
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/Envs/magicmall2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in _get_response
Traceback (most recent call last):
    iter(patterns)
  File "/root/Envs/magicmall2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 409, in url_patterns
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'magic_mall.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

the project is running fine on my windows laptop.but couldn't work properly while i am deploying it on server.
my uwsgi is running on virtualenv with python+django

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket=192.168.17.128:8001
# http=192.168.199.133:8001
chdir=/root/Desktop/MagicMall/magic_mall
wsgi-file=magic_mall/wsgi.py
processes=4
threads=2
master=True
pidfile=uwsgi.pid
daemonize=uwsgi.log
virtualenv=/root/Envs/magicmall2
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;


sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;
upstream magicmall {
server 192.168.17.128:8001; 
}

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.magicmall.com;
location /admin {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass magicmall;
}

location /ckeditor {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass magicmall;
}

    location / {
        root   /root/Desktop/front_end_pc;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  api.magicmall.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass magicmall;
    }
}
```

}

no idea why these happen ...

update:
I think I know the reason now.
it's django1 in my virtualenv, this virtualenv should running on django 3,but it is actually running on django1..

```
(magicmall2) [root@localhost urls]# pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
amqp                          5.1.1
asgiref                       3.4.1
async-generator               1.10
async-timeout                 4.0.2
attrs                         21.4.0
backports.zoneinfo            0.2.1
billiard                      3.6.4.0
cached-property               1.5.2
celery                        5.1.2
certifi                       2022.6.15
cffi                          1.15.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.12
click                         7.1.2
click-didyoumean              0.3.0
click-plugins                 1.1.1
click-repl                    0.2.0
colorama                      0.4.5
contextvars                   2.4
cryptography                  37.0.2
dataclasses                   0.8
defusedxml                    0.7.1
Deprecated                    1.2.13
diff-match-patch              20200713
Django                        1.11.29
django-ckeditor               6.3.2
django-cors-headers           3.2.1
django-crispy-forms           1.13.0
django-crontab                0.7.1
django-formtools              2.2
django-import-export          1.2.0
django-js-asset               1.2.3
django-redis                  4.11.0
django-reversion              3.0.9
django-smtp-ssl               1.0
djangorestframework           3.11.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0
dnspython                     2.2.1
drf-extensions                0.7.1
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
eventlet                      0.33.1
future                        0.18.2
greenlet                      1.1.2
h11                           0.13.0
httplib2                      0.9.2
idna                          3.3
immutables                    0.18
importlib-metadata            4.8.3
importlib-resources           5.4.0
itsdangerous                  2.0.1
kombu                         5.1.0
MarkupPy                      1.14
odfpy                         1.4.1
openpyxl                      3.0.10
outcome                       1.1.0
packaging                     21.3
Pillow                        8.4.0
pip                           21.3.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.29
py3Fdfs                       2.2.0
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pycparser                     2.21
pycryptodome                  3.15.0
pycryptodomex                 3.9.4
PyJWT                         2.4.0
PyMySQL                       1.0.2
pyOpenSSL                     19.1.0
pyparsing                     3.0.7
PySocks                       1.7.1
python-alipay-sdk             3.0.4
pytz                          2022.1
PyYAML                        6.0
redis                         4.3.3
requests                      2.27.1
rsa                           4.8
selenium                      3.141.0
setuptools                    59.6.0
six                           1.16.0
sniffio                       1.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
sqlparse                      0.4.2
tablib                        3.1.0
trio                          0.19.0
trio-websocket                0.9.2
typing_extensions             4.1.1
tzdata                        2022.1
urllib3                       1.26.9
uWSGI                         2.0.20
vine                          5.0.0
wcwidth                       0.2.5
wheel                         0.37.1
wrapt                         1.14.1
wsproto                       1.0.0
xadmin                        0.6.1
xlrd                          2.0.1
xlwt                          1.3.0
zipp                          3.6.0
```

but the actual running django:

```
(magicmall2) [root@localhost urls]# python -m django --version
1.11.29
(magicmall2) [root@localhost urls]#
```

Comment: You are not actually running a web server as "root", are you?  That's something you never, never, NEVER do.  You need to log in as a normal user.

Comment: yes...it is running as root..it's a test env

Comment: is this why this error happens?

Comment: Please include magic_mall.urls in your question

Comment: solved..turns out i was running virtualenv on django1..,big mistake.  change to django3 now ...thank u ,man